# How sklearn.metrics.r2_score works

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statistics

I tried to implement formula from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#Definitions) but results are different. Why is it so?

```
y_true = np.array([1, 1, 0])
y_pred = np.array([1, 0, 1])

r2 = r2_score(y_true, y_pred)
print(r2)

y_true_mean = statistics.mean(y_true)
r2 = 1 - np.sum((y_true - y_pred) ** 2) / np.sum((y_true - y_true_mean) ** 2)
print(r2)
```

> -1.9999999999999996
> 0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what statistics package you use, but it seems that the different outcome originates there. Try to use `np.mean` instead. That gives the same R2 as sklearn:

```python
import numpy as np

y_true = np.array([1, 1, 0])
y_pred = np.array([1, 0, 1])

y_true_mean = np.mean(y_true)
r2 = 1 - np.sum((y_true - y_pred) ** 2) / np.sum((y_true - y_true_mean) ** 2)
print(r2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYwxCsMwDEV3n0KjFdomceeepJRgiKEZrAjFHnx6V8GmQylokN77@lzSe6d7rVvkXRJQjlzAH0BsTFmS5AAPPW5exBf7nC@gM71QJUtYf@WkXmV/XWLw1CLnZhtFI07hDNdTHDnaLhS0VoRhAIcw/gt8i3vKsGyUrDis9QM)